# Ising model critical temperature from divergence of the high temperature series

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, ising-model

Consider the Ising model on a d-dimensional hypercubic lattice with nearest-neighbor coupling $J=1$: $$H=-\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}\sigma_i\sigma_j$$

For small $\beta$ (corresponding to high temperature), we can expand the partition function in terms of a high temperature series involving a "sum over loops" in the lattice. So the free energy density is written as $$-\beta f=\frac{1}{N}\log Z=\frac{1}{N}\log \sum_{L=0}^\infty C_N(L)\tanh^L\beta + \text{regular terms.}$$

Here $N$ is the number of sites in the lattice and $C_N(L)$ is the number of sets of loops (polygons) of total length $L$ in a lattice of size $N$. If I now take the limit $N\to\infty$, it's clear that for small enough $\tanh\beta$ the series in the logarithm converges so the overall $\frac{1}{N}\log$ term goes to $0$ leaving $f$ analytic.

My confusion is about what happens at the critical point $\beta_c$. This is the smallest $\beta$ for which the infinite system high temperature series diverges, right? How can I rigorously show the non-analytic behavior of $$\frac{1}{N}\log \sum_{L=0}^\infty C_N(L)\tanh^L\beta$$ as $N\to\infty$ at $\beta=\beta_c$?

Comment: The simplest way seems to be to work directly with the original expression of the free energy (that is, bypassing the high-temperature expansion). That the latter is non-analytic at some point $\beta_{\rm c}\in (0,\infty)$ when $d\geq 2$ then follows from standard arguments: prove that there is spontaneous magnetization at sufficiently low temperatures (usually, by the Peierls' argument), that there is no spontaneous magnetization at high enough temperatures (here you can use the high-temperature expansion) and correlation inequalities to show that the magnetization is increasing with $\beta$.

Comment: If you want to analyze *directly* the high-temperature expansion of the free energy, then the most promising way is to go one step further and expand the logarithm (using the cluster expansion). This provides a series for the free energy, converging for small enough $\beta$.  This does not seem to be a very promising way to attack the problem, but such an approach has been used (together with series coming from the low-temperature expansion) to extract (non-rigorously) information on the critical properties of the model, starting in the 1960s.

Comment: Thanks @YvanVelenik for your comments! This may require a post but I'm wondering if I'm being naive in the following argument to show non-analyticity of $f$ from high T expansion: Let $x=\tanh \beta$. If I assume that $C_N(L)\sim \alpha^L$ for $L<<N$, then for a suitable $\epsilon>0$, $\frac{1}{N}\log\sum C_N x^L>\frac{1}{N}\log\sum^{\epsilon N} C_N x^L \sim \frac{1}{N}\log\sum^{\epsilon N} \alpha^L x^L \to \epsilon \log(\alpha x)$ asymptotically as long as $\alpha x > 1$. This then shows non-analyticity of $f$ at $\beta_c$ since the $\epsilon \log(\alpha x)$ appears only at $\beta>\beta_c$.

Comment: I should be more precise: the contribution to $f$ from the $\frac{1}{N}\log$ only "turns on" above $\beta_c$, below $\beta_c$ it contributes $0$ and $f$ remains regular. This discontinuous "turning on" is indicative of singular behavior, no? I know that this isn't a rigorous argument at all, but does it capture the essence?

Comment: In my first comment, I should have been clear that $0<<L<<N$.

Comment: [I removed one of my comments, as it contains a mistaken claim.]

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Why would $C_N(L)\sim\alpha^L$? Or, rather, your constant $\alpha$ diverges with $N$. Just look at $L=4$; then $C_N(4)$ grows like $N$, since the corresponding loop can be placed anywhere in the box. For $L=8$, $C_N(8)$ grows even faster, as $N^2$ (two loops, each placed at an arbitrary position). More generally, As long as $L\ll N$, $C_N(L)$ will grow roughly as $N^{c L}$ for some constant $c>0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was tacitly assuming a fixed $N$ and implicitly noted that $\alpha$ should depend on $N$. Even so, my argument doesn't work. Thanks for the insight.